# Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created error occurs in c# winform

Tags: c#, delegates, controls, invoke

I have a custom control inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Button.

And I have a property called Enabled and DelegateProperty.

```
public class Button : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    public bool DelegateProperty { get; set; }


    public new bool Enabled
    {
        get { return base.Enabled; }
        set
        {
            if (DelegateProperty)
            {
                MethodInvoker action = delegate
                {
                    base.Enabled = value;
                };
                this.BeginInvoke(action);
            }
            else
                base.Enabled = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And when I set DelegateProperty as true in that control, it gives me this error in design time.

"Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created"

I have tried to avoid MethodInvoker when it's design time using

```
bool isInDesignMode = LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime || Debugger.IsAttached == true;
```

But, still I get this error in design time.

How can I avoid running BeginInvode method in design time?

Comment: You've tried the `DesignMode` property that every control inherits?

Comment: What is the meaning of BeginInvoke usage?